# Why offset argument in fs.write doesn't work with buffer but does with string

Tags: node.js

i'm facing an issue with fs.write(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback);

If I do:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fd = fs.openSync('./test', 'w');
var firstString = '012';
var secondString = 'hello';

fs.writeSync(fd, firstString, 0, firstString.length);
fs.writeSync(fd, secondString, 2, secondString.length);
```

The content of the file "test" is: "01hello" as expected

But if I do

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fd = fs.openSync('./test', 'w');
var firstBuffer = new Buffer('012');
var secondBuffer = new Buffer('hello');

fs.writeSync(fd, firstString, 0, firstBuffer.length);
fs.writeSync(fd, secondString, 2, secondBuffer.length);
```

The content of the file "test" is "012" and I got the following error:

```
fs.js:429
   return binding.write(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);

Error: off + len > buffer.length
     at Object.fs.writeSync (fs.js:429:18)
[...]
```

Could you explain me why I got an error with buffers?

Comment: you miss `-2`, `fs.writeSync(fd, secondString, 2, secondBuffer.length - 2);`

Comment: `fs.writeSync(fd, "your string", 2, 'utf8');` when you pass a string, the `length` must be `encoding`, a number may cause an error on some platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to your answer I figured out there is a difference when you give a string or a buffer: the position argument is not the same.

with a string, the position arguments is number 2:

```
fs.writeSync(fd, secondString, 2, secondString.length);
```

with a buffer, the position argument is number 4, as the doc says:

```
fs.writeSync(fd, secondBuffer, 0, secondBuffer.length, 2);
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From the Node.js documentation http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback

> offset and length determine the **part of the buffer** to be written.

Your code is trying to access bytes 2 to 7 (2+5). If you want to append to the file, use fs.append